# How do I disable time synchronization in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, time

I want to set my clock 15 minutes forward but when I do that manually using the following command:

```
sudo date --set "21 Nov 2015 15:10:00"
```

the time re-sets itself by synchronizing/updating with  ubuntu time server. I want to disable this feature.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your Lubuntu main menu there is an entry called Time and Date under System Tools.  Select this and then a new Window will open.  Select Unlock.  You will be asked for your password.  Under configuration select Manual.  Make your adjustments and then close.

Comment: Please accept the answer so we can close the question

Comment: Unfortunately after a reboot, the time automatically updated itself :(